# Key not valid for use in specified state error when using ProtectedData.Unprotect

Tags: asp.net, cryptography

I have a little problem in using a simple ProtectedData.Unprotect call, here's the code I'm sharing, maybe I'm missing something here.

```
public static byte[] SampleDecrypt(IEncrypted symmetricallyEncrypted, string base64DpapiLocalEncyrptedKey)
        {
            if (base64DpapiLocalEncryptedKey == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("base64DpapiLocalEncryptedKey");
            }


            byte[] unprotectedKey = 
               ProtectedData.Unprotect(
                    base64DpapiLocalEncyrptedKey,
                    null,
                    DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);


            return unprotectedKey;
        }
```

Where base64DpapiLocalEncyrptedKey is:
"ABCCENCMnd8CFdERjHoAVV/Pl+sMAAAA4q4wemrun5a67ohPku3cIAQCCCBAAAAKKKDZgAAqAAAABADDDCvGV5W6fCNcWbb9LPZp2U3AAAYYYSBBBCgDDDDEAAAANlpDcUbBvGqMyHXk8CPtUEoBBBBlB1TtMZRC05ASxGV1/c3U548eVSPUO4X307ZDjRYytjNC35Di92q9RQAAACN//xNkexvIrGULI9GG9MdyS9Lee=="

when I ran the above it gives me the "Key not valid for use in specified state"

Thank you so much in advance guys!

Comment: when I googled I got this "If you use this method during impersonation, you may receive the following error: "Key not valid for use in specified state." To prevent this error, load the profile of the user you want to impersonate before calling the method." is this about right?

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out the problem. DPAPI pairs the encrypted key with your machine (assuming it's encrypted using a machine scope) in my case, localmachine scope was used.

Thought it may help anyone out there having the same issues. Try the key onto different machines to see if one works and not on the other to verify that you have a wrong key.

I created a new key off of a different server and was able to use it.